# C language:installing libraries on codeblocks

Tags: c, sockets, installation, codeblocks

I am coding in c language on codeblocks. I want to use the  <sys/socket.h> for socket programming.
But the compiler gives a fatal error.

please tell how to install this header file

Comment: The `<sys/socket.h>` header file is a POSIX specific header file, i.e. it's only available on e.g. Linux or macOS systems. If you're programming on Windows please do some research about the *windows sockets* (a.k.a. "winsock") library

Comment: Please provide details like which operating system/compiler you are using and how you are compiling your program.

Comment: Are you trying to do this on a Windows machine?

Comment: I m using Windows 10

Comment: If you have both the VS compiler and MinGW compilers installed, make sure Code::Blocks is using MinGW.

Comment: Well... "GNU's not UNIX" doesn't mean that GNU is Windows :)